# Iterate Gridview through jquery and generate XML output

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have grid view and using databinding in my user control page. From my javascript code I need to iterate through the entire header and its values of the gridview to generate an xml format output to be stored in the database. I am quite new to javascript/jquery and have tried a number of things but not sure if am getting close yet.

my **ascx** page with the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewFreeformResults" ControlStyle-CssClass="FF_" OnRowDataBound="FreeFormFields_OnRowDatabound" ShowHeader="true"  runat="server" SkinID="SearchGridResultsClassicConfigurable"  PageSize="15"  Width="750px" AllowPaging="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Setup">                    
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-CssClass="FF_FieldID" DataField="FieldID" HeaderText="FieldID"   />
        <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-CssClass="FF_FieldName" DataField="FieldName" HeaderText="FieldName"   />
        <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-CssClass="FF_Description" DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"   />        
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderText="RE Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderControlREValue" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderText="LE Value">            
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderControlLEValue" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ItemTemplate>                            
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My **Hosting** aspx page callinig the user control:

```
<uc1:FreeFormLensDetails ID="FreeFormGrid" runat="server" />
```

Desired **XML** format:

```
<ItemValues>
  <item>
    <FieldID>1</FieldID>
    <FieldName>Field Name</FieldName>
    <Description>description here</Description>
    <REValue>10.99</REValue>
    <LEValue>11.50</LEValue>
  <item>
<ItemValues>
```

Perhaps something similar to this but in XML? 
[Iterate Gridview through jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036568/iterate-gridview-through-jquery)

Comment: Any specific reason for generating xml using jquery instead of server side code?

Comment: Wanted to avoid postback I guess. Also, other fields on this page are doing a similar thing, storing data into hidden fields that are later passed to server-side and database. It may not be the best solution but I wanted to keep consistent with the existing functionality.